# How to set the background color of a OpenGL enhanced QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qwidget

I have a custom QGraphicsView class where I try to set the background color in its constructor.
These work in non-OpenGL mode:

```
QColor backgroundColor(50,50,50,255);
setBackGroundBrush(backgroundColor)
```

and

```
QPalette myPal = this->palette();
myPal.setColor(this->backgroundRole(), backgroundColor);
this->setPalette(myPal);
```

However in OpenGL mode the first produces a white screen clearing, while the second clears the widget with the given color. I can also see for a few milliseconds the actual item ought to be drawn in between repaints.

If I don't set the background color at all a white background is set, and everything functions just fine.